# How to get system time (server redis) on python

Tags: python, redis

When I use Redis client console with command:

`Redis-Server(Ubuntu):0>time
  1) 1462519232
  2) 200666`

How do I can get it in python like 1462519232.200666

Version redis lib I use redis 2.10.5

Comment: `import time; time.time()`

Comment: @Klaus No, time.time() get localtime. I want retrieve time form server(the server is running redis) and my client is running python

Comment: A UNIX timestamp is always GMT, so there is only going to be the difference of how much your computers clocks are off.

Comment: my case, I use time from server to synchronize to computers clocks

Comment: There is a protocol for that, it's call NTP. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for keyword. Maybe it resolve my problem

Answer (score 3):

You could use third-package: [redis](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/2.10.5)

It supports `redis`'s built-in `time` command:

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r.time()
(1462524221, 416010)
```

Comment: Yes. Actually that's what I need when I ask this question.